# Programming in Ada error in executing files

Tags: runtime-error, ada

I just started programming in Ada and I have a problem in executing some files .adb.

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO; 
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO; 
procedure Trapeze(A:integer;B: Integer;C :Integer;D: Integer) is
   procedure Traceligne(C:Character;X:Integer) is 
   begin 
      for I in 1 .. X loop 
         Put("C"); 
   end loop; 
   end Traceligne; 
   H:Integer:=C; 
   Alpha:Integer:=D; 
   Decd:integer:=A; 
   Decg:integer:=B;

begin 
   for I in 1 .. H loop
      Traceligne(' ',Decd); 
      Traceligne('*',Alpha); 
      Traceligne(' ',Decg); 
      Decd:=Decd-Integer(Decd*I/H); 
      Decg:=Decg-Integer(Decg*I/H);
      Alpha:=Alpha+Integer(Decd*I/H)+Integer(Decg*I/H);    
   end loop;
get(x);
Trapeze(1,2,3,4) 
end Trapeze;
```

i have this code error:

> line 1: with: command not found.

I don't know the reason of this message .

PS: The question is simple for some programs my computer recognize  the `with Ada.Text_IO`command and for some others it gives me the error mentioned before I don't know why.
In fact I found the real problem its in the compilation of the file it compiles but stops in gcc and doesn't continue to the gnatbind and gnatlink I hope you will have some suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want someone to take time out of their busy day to help you, please spend a little time crafting a usable question.  See these links - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  and http://sscce.org/

Comment: What other languages do you know?

Comment: try googling for "with: command not found." there're some answers out there.

Comment: `with` is an Ada keyword with a meaning vaguely akin to C's `#include` or (a little closer) Java's `import`.

Comment: Example: with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
procedure Trapeze(A:integer;B: Integer;C :Integer;D: Integer) is
   procedure Traceligne(C:Character;X:Integer) is
      begin
      for I in 1 .. X loop
         Put("C");
      end loop;
end Traceligne;

H:Integer:=C;
Alpha:Integer:=D;
   Decd:integer:=A;
   Decg:integer:=B;
   begin
   for I in 1 .. H loop
     Traceligne(' ',Decd);
   Traceligne('*',Alpha);
   Traceligne(' ',Decg);
   Decd:=Decd-Integer(Decd*I/H);
   Decg:=Decg-Integer(Decg*I/H);
   
   end loop;

   end Trapeze;

Comment: Edit your original question and paste in the text.  Then highlight what you pasted and press the `{}` button to indent it 4 characters so it will be formatted as code.

Comment: (But it's sounding like the build process doesn't think the file is Ada and is trying to interpret it as a script or some such.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the `command not found` message is that you're trying to execute the `trapeze.adb` file rather than an executable program built from it (`trapeze` or, on Windows, `trapeze.exe`).

The reason why GNAT hasn't built an executable program is that, in GNAT, a main program must be a **parameterless** procedure; presumably some of your test programs were parameterless, but this one isn't.

If you were hoping to be able to supply the parameters from the command line, as

```
$ ./trapeze 1 2 3 4
```

then you need to use [`Ada.Command_Line`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-15.html) to retrieve them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my program I did trapeze(1,2,3,4) at the end and the problem still persist I also tried with ada.command_Line; Use Ada.command_Line and it doesn't work.

Comment: What I did is I retired all the parameters from the procedure at the beginning and i put get ... It has finally worked so Thanks!